# Check android connection from outside class / get system service

Tags: android

I am trying to check for a internet connection in a class that is not an activity.

i am using the following code:

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();        
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but the following line of code is underlined red:

```
getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
```

I am assuming that it is because it cannot get systemService. How can i get the system service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the `Context` from the `Activity` you are in

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context c) {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

So if calling from an `Activity` use something like this to pass the `Activity`'s `Context`

```
boolean hasConnection = isNetworkAvailable(this);
```

Obviously after creating an instance of the enclosing class

Answer (score 0):

its `context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)` to use that activity is derrived from context which is why you can just use `getSystemService` in an activity without having context before it

Answer (score 0):

Use This :-

```
public class CheckInternet {
    
        public Context context;
    
        public CheckInternet(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
    
        public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    
            return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
        }  }
```

And Call Like This:-

```
CheckInternet checkInternet = new CheckInternet(this);
boolean connection = checkInternet.isNetworkConnected();
```